# Is it safe to embed a google form on a website without an SSL Certificate?

Tags: tls, html, iframe, google-apps

I designed a Google Form for a website which does not have an SSL Certificate. I have planned to embed it onto a page using an iframe tag. I am currently testing it and have published a test page with the form, but when I fill out any of the fields Google Chrome says that the page is,

> Not Secure

but it is in red unlike the normal grey.

The form is not asking for any information such as credit card numbers, but it is asking for name, email, and some other information.

Is this safe to embed the Google Form or does the site need an SSL Cerficicate?

Comment: Name and email are PII, which is regulated in many jurisdictions. What do you mean by "safe"? I'm not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: There is nothing preventing a MITM from replacing your google form with a completely different one (or anything else for that matter). This is absolutely not safe by any definition, you need to use TLS. See https://doesmysiteneedhttps.com/ for more.